# Django OperationalError, lacking id column

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models

I am having trouble making my newly created table (blog_sp500_post_noid_sorted) show up. Whenever I try to open the table under the admin page, I got the following error message:

```
OperationalError at /admin/blog/sp500_post_noid_sorted/
no such column: blog_sp500_post_noid_sorted.id
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/blog/sp500_post_noid_sorted/
Django Version: 1.8
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such column: blog_sp500_post_noid_sorted.id
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 318
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.9
Python Path:    
['C:\\Python27\\djangogirls\\mysite',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 15 Apr 2018 11:30:20 -0700
```

The table was created by inserting columns from an existing table in the database using SQLite command.
I noticed that an ‘id’ column was always created for models in Django. However, such id column was absent for tables created using SQLite command. Is there any way for Django to ignore the absence of id column or do I have to manually create an id column?

I added the following model after the table was created via SQLite command:

```
class sp500_post_NoID_sorted(models.Model):
    Day = models.DateField(blank=False, default=datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    Symbol = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='N/A')
    LastPrice = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='N/A')
    FiftyTwoWkChg = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='N/A')
    FiftyTwoWkHi = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='N/A')
    FiftyTwoWkLo = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='N/A')
    DivYild = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='N/A')
    TrailPE = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='N/A')
    ForwardPE = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='N/A')
    PEG_Ratio = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='N/A')
    PpS = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='N/A')
    PpB = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='N/A')
    Market_Cap = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='N/A')
    Free_Cash_Flow = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='N/A')
    Market_per_CashFlow = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='N/A')
    Enterprise_per_EBITDA = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='N/A')
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='N/A')
```

Comment: how is your model specified?  It doesn't need an id field but it does need a primary key

Comment: post your models.py and I can try to help further.

Answer (score 0):

If your models are defined in Django you should be able to set the primary key on the appropriate column.

See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#field-options) and scroll down to primary_key. Add that option to your model's field that is the primary key, then makemigrations and migrate.

Comment: I never specified primary_key status to any of my model fields, Django automatically added an “id” field with the primary_key attribute to any new model specified in models.py. Do I have to add an id field to any new table that was created with SQLite command? Or is there a customary way when creating new tables with SQLite? Please see my edited question for the model that I added for my new table.